# Quotes inside quotes inside quotes

Tags: python, django

The question is about complex quotes structures. Is this correct syntax to use for Django 1.6+ ?

```
onclick="window.open('{% url 'namespace:name' %}');"
```

Comment: If you need you can escape the quotes inside with \ I reckon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes inside the template tags do not conflict with what's outside. The template tag is rendered before the JS is run, so the JS will just see the result.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I've read about this on the web, although it was 2-levels on quotes. Wanted to be sure.